# SmartGWT ListGrid FilterEditor getValue

Tags: grid, smartgwt

I have a little appliation that shows MySQL data in web browser ListGrid. It has 14 columns.
I would like to upgrade it so the user could add query parameters.
For this job the best I could imagine is the `grid.setShowFilterEditor()` that put text boxes above the column headers and will live together with the column header when moved or resized.
I planned to use the filter button `FilterEditorSubmitHandler()` to get the filter values and run the query.

Unfortunately, I can not find any solution to get the text from a certain filter box eg. the value that was written by the user into the box above Column_#1. Is there any way to do that or this FilterEditor grown together with the DataSources object, and not available for any other data binding?

Something like this, but without using DataSource:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_sortfilter_disable_filter

Comment: Thanks, then the best I can do is adding extra empty text box objects or editable cells in the grid, or simply add individual text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, filter editor works on `com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource` only.
If you want to have `filterEditor` in `ListGrid`, you have to use `DataSource` or go for some custom implementation.